# Changing `SEXP` structure inside an R package

Tags: c++, c, rcpp, r-package

I have developed an R package which provides a wrapper around the CVODE function of the [SUNDIALS](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials) (ODE solving library).

The package includes source functions (in the `src` and `inst/include` folders) and compiles the static linking (`.a`) and `.dll` files on the fly (while compiling the package), so it does not require `SUNDIALS` package to be installed on the system as a pre-requisite. The package source can be found at

https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod

However, `SUNDIALS` requires that the ODE function have the following signature

```
int ODE_fun (realtype time, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data);
```

Where `realtype`, `N_Vector` are data types defined by the SUNDIALS library. Thus, an example ODE function would be defined as follows

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#include <cvode/cvode.h>               /* prototypes for CVODE fcts., consts. */
#include <nvector/nvector_serial.h>    /* serial N_Vector types, fcts., macros */

#define Ith(v,i)  NV_Ith_S(v,i-1)

#define k1  0.04
#define k2  1e04
#define k3  3e07


int test1 (realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot){  // , void *user_data

  // static keyword before int is not really required here

  realtype y1 = Ith(y, 1);
  realtype y2 = Ith(y, 2);
  realtype y3 = Ith(y, 3);

  realtype yd1 = Ith(ydot, 1);
  realtype yd2 = Ith(ydot, 2);
  realtype yd3 = Ith(ydot, 3);

  yd1 = -k1 * y1 + k2 * y2 * y3;
  yd3 = k3 * y2 * y2;
  yd2 = -y1 - y3;


  return(0);
}
```

Compiling this function, however, requires `cvode.h` and `nvector_serial.h` header files, thus requiring SUNDIALS to be installed.

However, I want the user to be able to define ODEs using `Rcpp` only, i.e.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#define k1  0.04
#define k2  1e04
#define k3  3e07


int test2 (double t, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot, void *user_data) {

  ydot[0] = -k1 * y[0] + k2 * y[1] * y[2];
  ydot[2] = k3 * y[1] * y[1];
  ydot[1] = -y[0] - y[2];

  return(0);
}
```

which will then be fed to `cvode` function as an `SEXP` (here `ODE_fun` parameter) from the package which has the signature

```
cvode(NumericVector time_vec, NumericVector IC, 
      SEXP ODE_fun, double reltolerance, NumericVector abstolerance)
```

Currently `ODE_fun` is a function pointer with the `typedef`

```
typedef int (*funcPtr)(realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data);
```

`test1` is converted to `XPtr` using the following code

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<funcPtr> putFunPtrInXPtr() {

    XPtr<funcPtr> testptr(new funcPtr(&test), false);
    return testptr;

}
```

The entire procedure to run a sample example can be found at the package [wiki](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/wiki).

I am not sure how to input `test2` (ODE function defined using `Rcpp` only) and convert it into a function with signature required by `CVODE` solver inside the package. Any suggestions or directions or if there is a better way to achieve my purpose would be highly welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Need to write `as<T>` and `wrap()` functions. See http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/

Comment: @coatless - thanks! Will take a look at your article.

Comment: I could not find the definition of `realtype` -- isn't that maybe a simple `typedef` for `double` or `float`?  Ditto with `N_vector`?  Worst case, add _one_ layer of translation from SUNDIALS type (that you know) to atomic types / Rcpp types known by Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks, yes, `realtype`  is a `typedef` for `double` and `N_Vector` is similar to `vector`.  Your suggestion is exactly what I wanted to implement, but I am not sure how to extract elements in the package when `test2` is input. A toy-example would be extremely helpful.